# sklearn log_loss different number of classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using log_loss with sklearn

```
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
print log_loss(true, pred,normalize=False)
```

and i have following error:

```
ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of classes 38, 2
```

It is really strange to me since, the arrays look valid:

```
print pred.shape
print np.unique(pred)
print np.unique(pred).size
(19191L,)
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37]
38

print true.shape
print np.unique(true)
print np.unique(true).size
(19191L,)
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37]
38
```

What is wrong with the log_loss? Why it throws the error?

Sample data:

```
pred: array([ 0,  1,  2, ...,  3, 12, 16], dtype=int64)
true: array([ 0,  1,  2, ...,  3, 12, 16])
```

Comment: Can you post some data for pred and true?  It looks like your labels are being passed incorrectly.

Comment: Added to the original post

Comment: Log loss is to be used to assess the accuracy of probabilities - it is expecting an array of probabilities associated with every possible label (you are passing only label).  I believe your pred variable should be an array of n-arrays, where n is the number of labels.

Answer (score 19):

It's simple, you are using the prediction and not the probability of your prediction. Your `pred` variable contains

```
[ 1 2 1 3 .... ] #Classes : 1, 2 or 3
```

but to use `log_loss` it should contain something like:

```
 #each element is an array with probability of each class
 [[ 0.1, 0.8, 0.1] [ 0.0, 0.79 , 0.21] .... ]
```

To obtain these probabilities use the function `predict_proba`:

```
pred = model.predict_proba(x_test)
eval = log_loss(y_true,pred)
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the log_loss method, true array is fit and transformed by a LabelBinarizer which changes its dimensions. So, the check that true and pred have similar dimensions doesn't mean that log_loss method will work because true's dimensions change. If you just have binary classes, I suggest you use this log_loss cost function else for multiple classes, this method doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

From the log_loss documentation:

> **y_pred** : array-like of float, shape = (n_samples, n_classes) or (n_samples,)
>
> **Predicted probabilities, as returned by a classifier’s predict_proba method**. If y_pred.shape = (n_samples,) the probabilities provided are assumed to be that of the positive class. The labels in y_pred are assumed to be ordered alphabetically, as done by preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.

You need to pass probabilities not the prediction labels.